# Figure of `inverted residual with linear bottleneck` shown in mobilenetV2 paper is compliant with MobileNetV2 implementation of `Pytorch`

Tags: pytorch, mobilenet

The [MobileNet V2 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04381) introduced `inverted residual with linear bottleneck` block. It is shown diagrammatically in Fig. 3(b) (Same is shown in Fig. 3 of [MobileNetV3 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02244)) and mathematically in Table 1 of this paper.

[image: Fig. 3(b)]
[image: Table 1]
[image: Pytorch Inverted residual Block]

Fig. 3(b) shows that the shortcut connection is coming from the `input bottleneck` (`linear bottleneck`) to the `output bottleneck` created from `ReLU6,1*1 convolution`, which is wrong as ReLU6 squashes too much information if dimensionality reduction happens

But Table 1 shows that the shortcut connection is coming from the `input bottleneck` to the `output bottleneck` (`linear bottleneck`) which is created by 1*1 convolution without ReLU6. The `pytorch` `MobilenetV2` model follows this same table.

So can I understand that this Fig.3(b) is drawn wrongly? It should be like the Table 1 in the paper?